# How to parse 2022-07-22 06:36:51 GMT +0530 in PHP including the time zone?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Our application has an external input source of date as in the below format:

```
2020-09-17 07:48:22 GMT +0530
```

I want to parse it in PHP to store it into MySQL DB.

I have tried using `date_create()` as below:

```
$d = date_create('2020-09-17 07:48:22 GMT +0530');
dd($d); //This is for laravel
```

The output is:

[image]

Even if I give different offset like +06:30, the output is same.
So how will I convert to date object along with the time zone, so that I can store it directly in database.

Comment: Keep in mind that Laravel comes pre-installed with Carbon: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/. `Carbon::parse(...)` or `Carbon::createFromFormat()` can be used instead of `date_create()`, and might be better as Models support Carbon already for their `created_at`, `edited_at` and `deleted_at` timestamps.

Comment: Roughly ten date format standards are supported natively by php (and therefore Carbon), and people still invent variations. Just use a ding-dang UNIX time! No timezones! No ambiguity! *Deep breath...* But anywhere `strtotime` works, `Carbon::parse()` should work and the result will be much more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) instead

```
$d = strtotime('2020-09-17 07:48:22 GMT +0530');

dd($d);
```